# Oracle multiple replace

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

I have warranty offers column in Oracle table that is not cleansed and consistent. For instance,
in this table we have following data, and I only want to keep the highest warranty period in months (if not in months, I want to convert it). For instance from first record below, 18 months is highest and I want to keep data in months so "warranty_offrs" will be "18", Record #2 will be "12" instead of twelve, Record #6 will be "24", value will be integer number:

warranty_offrs (char 2000 bytes):

1. Record #1: "one year, 18 months, 24 weeks"
2. Record #2:"twelve months, 8 months, 60 days."
3. Record #3:"(30) months."
4. Record #4:"(60) months, 20 weeks."
5. Record #5: "1 year, 12 months, 18 months, 3 years, one month"
6. Record #6: "{12} weeks, {2} years, one month, twelve months."

Data has sometimes dots after months/days/weeks brackets with numbers (since its coming from different sources), and all sorts of combinations like above. I am doing this in Stored Procedure, and first tried to use replace to get ride of all the "(" ")" "[" "]" "{" "}" but still translation is left.

How can I achieve it, please let me know?

Answer (score 1):

Global Temp tables used from step 2-8 only contains relevant columns.

1. removed all kinds of irrelevant strings e.g. brackets, dots etc from the column using REPLACE command and load data into perm table. some columns were converted into lower letters for easier calculations later. This table contains all the columns.
2. Then I used your pivot code to pivot string values into rows e.g. warranty_offrs values "one month, 2 year, 3 days" will become 3 records, and i loaded it into another global temp table marked {table_name_US_ENG} (since there is same column exist in Spanish as well and sometimes its populated and if it is populated then I need to use value from that column).
3. Repeated step 2 for Spanish column and loaded pivoted only record into global temp {table_name_ESP} when spanish column has values.
4. Created lookup table to have two columns: word, number column e.g. "one","1", "ten","10" etc. This will help convert words to numbers in step 5
5. data from step 2, and step 3 tables performs lookup on lookup in step 4, and gets the numeric values for words. "1" for "one", "10" for "ten". To keep the period (year/months etc.) I used substr to concat both values back. Now all of my values in numbers and have period (year/days). This data gets loaded into another global temp table (will be repeated for Spanish column values to separate table).
6. Next step is to convert them to months. since there are only handful of these possibilities, I used case statement and convert them to month, and loaded into another global temp table (this step will be repeated for Spanish data)
7. Then I do following to get max month for us_eng column from us_eng GTT table:
   select id, max(mth_us_eng) keep (dense_rank first order by id)max_mth from gtt_table_us_eng. Result is then inserted to Global temp table.
   (this sql is repeated for global temp table with Spanish column to get max month)
8. left outer join English (left table) with Spanish (right) table, and get only records where there is match insert into last global temp table (phew!)
9. Now performed INNER JOIN with perm table from Step 1 with global temp table from step 8 and load results into final perm table.

Question:
How do we separate digit from string? In some cases column value doesn't have single space but are like "18months" instead of "18 months".

Comments:

- There are enough REPLACE functions in step 1 than the branches in my neighbor's maple tree.
- I hope my use of GTT wont increase global warming! (although I tried to mess up 12 months to 24).
- Hopefully, Spanish column lookup values improved my conversation skills for when I visit Mexican next time.

Any suggestion to tweak the code is welcome. :)

Comment: Looks OK to me, you described it well. I like comments the most, though :). Also, I added some more queries to my answer, see under **[EDIT, 26.03.2021]**.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to debug code you can't see. You said you wrote a stored procedure but it doesn't do what you wanted.

Replacing brackets is simple; you can use nested `REPLACE`s (which does the job, but is difficult to read and maintain) or - a better option - `TRANSLATE`:

```
SQL> with test (wo) as
  2    (select '(60) months, [20] weeks.' from dual union all
  3     select '{12} weeks, {2} years' from dual
  4    )
  5  select replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
  6           wo, '(', ''), ')', ''), '[', ''), ']', ''), '{', ''), '}', '') result_1,
  7         --
  8         translate(wo, 'a()[]{}', 'a') result_2
  9  from test;

RESULT_1                 RESULT_2
------------------------ ------------------------
60 months, 20 weeks.     60 months, 20 weeks.
12 weeks, 2 years        12 weeks, 2 years

SQL>
```

A of the rest of your problems: it looks as if that procedure will be quite long as there are many different cases you have to cover. Go step-by-step, test frequently. I don't think that there's a  *magic wand* solution.

---

You asked (in a comment) whether you can *parse* those strings. Yes; as each part of it is separated from another by a comma, you'd e.g.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '1 year, 12 months, 18 months, 3 years, one month' from dual)
  3  select trim(regexp_substr(col, '[^,]+', 1, level)) val
  4  from test
  5  connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ',') + 1;

VAL
------------------------------------------------
1 year
12 months
18 months
3 years
one month

SQL>
```

Then decide what to do with each of those values. As you have combination of words and numbers, singular and plural, whatnot, as I previously said - go step-by-step and change what you have to. Then merge the final result back, using `LISTAGG` function.

---

If you're working with more than a single row at a time, then you'll get quite a lot of duplicate rows. In that case, previous query should be adjusted accordingly. Here's how (I included additional `id` column to show which `val` belongs to which row):

```
SQL> with test (id, col) as
  2    (select 1, '1 year, 12 months, 18 months, 3 years, one month' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'twelve months, 8 months, 60 days.' from dual
  4    )
  5  select id,
  6         trim(regexp_substr(col, '[^,]+', 1, column_value)) val
  7  from test cross join
  8    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  9                        connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ',') + 1
 10                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 11  order by id, column_value;

        ID VAL
---------- ------------------------------------------------
         1 1 year
         1 12 months
         1 18 months
         1 3 years
         1 one month
         2 twelve months
         2 8 months
         2 60 days.

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT, 26.03.2021]**

If you want to add a space behind digit (if it doesn't exist, for example modify `18months` to `18 months`), then:

```
SQL> with
  2  test (col) as
  3    (select 'one year, 18months, 24 weeks' from dual),
  4  temp as
  5    -- split it to rows (you already know how to do that)
  6    (select trim(regexp_substr(col, '[^,]+', 1, level)) val
  7     from test
  8     connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ',') + 1
  9    )
 10  -- in CASE, check whether VAL contains a space. If so, return VAL. If not,
 11  -- add a space after digits
 12  select
 13    val,
 14    case when instr(val, ' ') = 0 then regexp_replace(val, '(\d+)', '\1 ')
 15         else val
 16    end new_val
 17  from temp;

VAL        NEW_VAL
---------- ----------
one year   one year
18months   18 months
24 weeks   24 weeks

SQL>
```

---

Also, maybe you don't need a *mapping* table for digits converted to words - there's a query which lets you do that; see if you can use it.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select   1 from dual union all
  3     select  18 from dual union all
  4     select  24 from dual union all
  5     select 673 from dual
  6    )
  7  select col,
  8         to_char(to_date(col, 'j'),'jsp') in_words
  9  from test;

       COL IN_WORDS
---------- ---------------------------------------------------
         1 one
        18 eighteen
        24 twenty-four
       673 six hundred seventy-three

SQL>
```

Comment: I just started so all I have is stored procedure name, and select statement to remove brackets.

Comment: I want to keep only highest duration, like for record in your Result_1, "60 months"  and "2 years". I believe this will only be possible once we convert all the durations to months. Is there way to traverse through the column string that can contain one or many or no commas? assume following value for this column= "one month, one year, two years, 12 month". Can I traverse through within the string and replace any instance of year/years/yrs to month after converting it? so one year will become "24 months" and then I can search the column again for the highest value to keep only highest #?

Comment: Well, "one year" should become "12 months" (not "24" months), at least here where I live. Can you do what you described? Sure, that's called *parsing*. I added some more info to the end of the answer; have a look.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This looked like horizontal pivot based on number of commas in the column value. Following is my logic based on your suggestion. create multiple lookup tables to translate "one" to "1", "twelve" to "12" then use another look up table to convert weeks/years/days to months. Finally get highest one and drop all the other records since they are duplicate anyway. However when I use you the code you shared, its not doing pivot. If you add one more line in inline query, you will notice its adding more repeating more than required. Let me know what do you think?

Comment: Exactly, you'll get A LOT of duplicates. I edited the answer and added code which shows how to dealt with it.

Comment: You're more than helpful, thank you. I will try it out and let you know how it works.

Comment: Please see below how solutions is coming along and let me know if you suggest any tweaks or improvements, and thanks again for your help.